# CrawlSpider not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new at scrapy and I'm having trouble with this code, its not parsing trough the links.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages')

import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'poder360.com'
    allowed_domais = ['poder360.com.br']
    start_urls = ['https://www.poder360.com.br']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=['poder360.com.br']),
        callback='parse_item', follow=True))

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        item = scrapy.Item()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        print(item['title'])
        return item
```

Comment: by looking at your code there is only class definition not class object  ...

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan what do you mean? scrapy initialize the class object

Comment: can you be more specific what is exactly your problem?, what do you get in the loggin? is working ? or throw error

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Comment: try to remove `allowed_domais` just for testing, and also post scrapers logs